# How to stop Nokogiri from changing XML when parsing

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm parsing this XML output from Julius:

```
<RECOGOUT SOURCEID="68">
  <SHYPO RANK="1" SCORE="223.648865">
    <WHYPO WORD="" CLASSID="<s>" PHONE="silB" CM="0.972"/>
    <WHYPO WORD="THE" CLASSID="THE" PHONE="dh iy" CM="0.640"/>
    <WHYPO WORD="ABOUT" CLASSID="ABOUT" PHONE="ah b aw t" CM="0.167"/>
    <WHYPO WORD="" CLASSID="</s>" PHONE="silE" CM="1.000"/>
  </SHYPO>
</RECOGOUT>
```

When I bring it into Nokogiri, it gets heavily modified.
`puts Nokogiri::XML.parse(t)`
gives:

```
<RECOGOUT SOURCEID="68">
  <SHYPO RANK="1" SCORE="223.648865">
    <WHYPO WORD="" CLASSID=""/><s>" PHONE="silB" CM="0.972"/&gt;
    <WHYPO WORD="THE" CLASSID="THE" PHONE="dh iy" CM="0.640"/>
    <WHYPO WORD="ABOUT" CLASSID="ABOUT" PHONE="ah b aw t" CM="0.167"/>
    <WHYPO WORD="" CLASSID=""/></s>" PHONE="silE" CM="1.000"/&gt;
  </SHYPO>
</RECOGOUT>
```

I know that when Nokogiri parses things it tries to modify it so that it becomes valid, but I thought if I parsed it as a document fragment, `puts Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(t)` things would improve, but I got the same result. Parsing as HTML also results in modification.

Why is Nokogiri parsing this so strangely and is there anything I can do to get the desired behaviour? Alternatively, should I file a bug report? Currently, I'm using a Regex (I know... It's a really limited case), but I'm sure my code would be easier to read if I could access things with xPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the XML is invalid is the `<s>` and `<\s>` being used as attributes. Once they are replaced, Nokogiri parses the values correctly. Thanks to @Wes for the help.